# Everyone's attacking me and I'm unable to pay my bounty

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started playing Skyrim on the PS3 and I killed my first dragon, learning 'Unrelenting Force'. Awesome! So I went into town, getting the letter from a friend. Bear in mind I had no autosaves and my last save was in Riverwood before meeting the Jarl. I accidentally used my shout and hit a citizen and two guards. They came after me and killed me. I cannot speak to them and they repeatedly kill me.

I went to Dragonsreach to start the Greybeards quest and they started attacking me. I picked a lock in sight, adding bounty, to see if paying it would clear my name, but the guards still kill me and don't demand bounty. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to surrender to them. Do so by sheathing your weapon. If this doesn't work, draw it then sheath it again, then try to talk to a guard.

Also try leaving the zone, waiting, and coming back with your weapon sheathed.

Comment: i have done this, it does not work

Comment: this does not work either. any more ideas?

Comment: @zac How much is your bounty ?

Comment: my bounty is 5.

Comment: the only other town i can fast travel to is riverwood. does that count?

Comment: hey i fast travelled to riverwood and he demanded my bounty. thanks even though thats not what you meant!

Comment: Well, that *is* what I meant :) Perfect !

Comment: well, i fast travelled to riverwood and a gaurd demanded my bounty. i paid and he took me back to dragonsreach. but everyone still wants to kill me!!!!

Comment: nevermind. i sheathed and he was fine.